# Contract for App Development and Service Maintainence

Tags: iphone, freelancing

I am going to develop iPhone application for clients, for fixed project cost. After that I will help maintain the application by charging a service/support fee.

Questions:

1. What should I put into the contract? Any samples I can use for reference?
2. Do developers normally give their source code to the client? And what should be the price differences for each?
3. How are service/support normally charged? Monthly or by the hour?

Any other advice welcome!

Comment: Source access and source code rights are completely negotiable, from free to over 100X more in price.  Depends on your business model.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the contract is written whether you give all the source code.

If I keep the source code then the price will be less, than if I give it to the client.

If there was a bug in my code, I tend to fix it for free, as it was my mistake, why should they pay for that (I need to improve my unit testing is the lesson from this bug).

As to the service charges, it depends on what was in the contract, and if they are paying some maintenance fee (I have often seen this to be 20% of the purchase price per year).

But, I would expect it to be by hour if you need to charge.

Much of this depends on if only one client will be using this software, or if it was general enough to sell to others also, as that would bring the price down, since many people are paying for feature improvements in their maintenance charge.